# Targeting seperate parts of a URL in Optimizely with REGEX

Tags: regex, url, testing, targeting, optimizely

I'm trying to target a set of URLs sharing the same template in Optimizely the https://chillisauce.com/hen/in-dublin/day

Specifically trying to target the hen/in- part and the /day part.

I've been testing this: /(hen)/in-.*/day[^/]+$

Although when testing the URL pattern in Optimizely it does not match.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Charlie

Comment: `\/(hen)\/in-.+\/day[^/]*$` Is probably what you want, but I don't know Optimizely, so I'll leave this as a comment (you may need to escape `/` and the + REQUIRES a character after day before the newline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Optimizely uses js regexes, so this should work:

```
\/(hen)\/in-.+\/day[^/]*$
```

See it in action here (allows you test on the fly modifications a little easier than optimizely's interface):
https://regex101.com/r/9Np4Oj/2

And you may want to consider following your later pattern (`[^/]`) here too.

```
\/(hen)\/in-[^/]+\/day[^/]*$
```